# Composite Filters for an ajax call to Google Cloud Search

Tags: ajax, google-cloud-platform

I have some javascript which is returning results from Google Cloud Search. An object stores the various filters and parameters for the search and feeds them to an ajax call to our Google Cloud server.

Here is an idea of what this object looks like when it is filled with parameters. Obviously most of the settings are variables set in the code, but I wanted to give a clear idea of what's going on here.

```
const dataSourceId = [the ID of our data source];
let searchParameters = {
  query: "spaceships",
  start: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  searchFilters:
    "collection:our_collection typefile:pdf", 
  useKeymatch: true,
  numKeymatchs: 3,
  keymatchTable:"ourDatabaseKeymatchTable",
  disableQueryInterpret: false,
  facetOptions: [
    {
      sourceName: dataSourceId,
      operatorName: 'typefile'
    }
  ],
  sortOptions:{}
};
```

And the connection object looks like this:

```
const searchUrl = "[url to our search index]";
return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: searchUrl,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(searchParameters),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
         console.log("Search Success");
      },
      error: function (e) {
         console.log(e.message);
      }
   });
```

Note the string of searchFilters deliminated by spaces. I would like to search this index using a composite filter so that I can return more than one file type in one query. I've seen some snips out there that seem to indicate we should be able to use the following in the searchFilters:

```
searchFilters: 
"collection:our_collection (typefile:pdf OR typefile:wordprocessor OR typefile:spreadsheet OR typefile:presentation)"
```

This didn't work out the gate. I have looked at the Google Cloud Search API for this and that seems pretty concise for folks who plan to interact with the search code directly. What I haven't been able to find is concise instructions on how to add it to our searchParameters object and get the POST to return results.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/settings.searchapplications#filter.compositefilter
https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudsearch_v1.query.html

I tried adding the following to the search parameters object as a test.

```
            dataSourceRestrictions: [
               {
                  source: {
                     "name": dataSourceId
                  },
                  filterOptions: [
                     {
                        filter: {
                           compositeFilter: {
                              subFilters: [
                                 {
                                    valueFilter: {
                                       operatorName: "typefile",
                                       value: {
                                          stringValue: "pdf"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    valueFilter: {
                                       operatorName: "typefile",
                                       value: {
                                          stringValue: "wordprocessor"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    valueFilter: {
                                       operatorName: "typefile",
                                       value: {
                                          stringValue: "spreadsheet"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    valueFilter: {
                                       operatorName: "typefile",
                                       value: {
                                          stringValue: "presentation"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
```

I tried many variations of this, at various depths and nothing has worked.

I am sure it's just a matter of finding the correct thing to call the endpoint for this object, but I cannot find the documentation to tell me what that name is.

Update: The more I work on this, the more I believe that I need access to the cloud search configuration to create a abilit y to add dataResourceRestirctions to the query. I just don't know what those settings are. Barring that, this is where I'm at so far, but I have no way of knowing if it is correct or not.

```
let filterNode = {
      "source": {
         "name": dataSourceId
      },
      "filterOptions": [
         {
            "compositeFilter": [
               {
                  "logicOperator": "OR",
                  "subFilters": [
                     {
                        "valueFilter": {
                           "operatorName": "typefile",
                           "value": {
                              "stringValue": "pdf"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "valueFilter": {
                           "operatorName": "typefile",
                           "value": {
                              "stringValue": "wordprocessor"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "valueFilter": {
                           "operatorName": "typefile",
                           "value": {
                              "stringValue": "spreadsheet"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "valueFilter": {
                           "operatorName": "typefile",
                           "value": {
                              "stringValue": "presentation"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   };
   
   let newFilterNode = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filterNode));
   optionsData.dataSourceRestrictions = newFilterNode;
```